# Javascript parameters: Having many parameters with many defaults

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I have a function with many parameters and many default value on them.

```
function foo(p1 ,p2, p3, p4, p5, p6){
    var p1 = p1 || 'default1'; 
    var p2 = p2 || 'default2'; 
    var p3 = p3 || 'default3'; 
    var p4 = p4 || 'default4'; 
    var p5 = p5 || 'default5'; 
    var p6 = p6 || 'default6'; 
}
```

How can I successfully only define like p1 and p6 only and not the rest?

I know in Scala you can do `foo(p1='something1',p6='something6')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take an object with properties for parameters.

For example:

```
function foo(options) {
    var p1 = options.p1 || 'default1'; 
    ...
}

foo({ p1: 3, p6: "abc" });
```

Comment: You could additionally loop through the options object and another object to minimize code size.

Comment: This also answers my question of "How to prevent writing a function with many parameters?"

Answer (score 2):

You could use one parameter that is an object and do jQuery extend for defaults like:

```
function foo(args) {
   jQuery.extend({
      p1: 'default1',
      p2: 'default2',
      p3: 'default3',
      p4: 'default4',
      p5: 'default5',
      p6: 'default6'
   }, args);
}

foo({p1: 'one', p6: 'six'});
```

Any properties defined in the second parameter to extend will overwrite properties in the first parameter.

Comment: Yeah, it's not necessary. You could just define the defaults as in the question like you did. Our answers would then be the same though, and that's not any fun ;)

Comment: Having that function is essential, jQuery or no: `function extend(dest, src) { for (prop in src) dest[prop] = src[prop]; return dest }` (naive implementation). This is the best option for constructor functions when inheriting, as you don't have to gather up all the values to pass onto the parent constructor when calling it - just apply your own required defaults with `extend` and do `ParentConstructor.call(this, args)`.

Answer (score 1):

Those are referred to as "named parameters", and there are several tutorials on them (using objects like in @SLaks's answer):

- http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/namedfunction.shtml (also see page 2 of that on detecting which parameters were passed reliably; `||` doesn't always work)
- http://www.spheredev.org/smforums/index.php?topic=1678.0