# Function parameter list too long | Minimizing

Tags: javascript

As this animation grows more complex, I keep adding in parameters, so that they are available on each call back.  6 total currently.

For example now I want to disable the input box while the message is being displayed so I have to add in yet another element - `in_element;`

**The Call:**

```
    Mo.C.movePane( cover_element, pane_element, 0, 0, 0, 'begin' );
```

**The Function:**

```
    movePane: function( cover_element, pane_element, start, end, index, state ) {
        if( ( state === 'begin' ) ) {
            start = parseInt( window.getComputedStyle( pane_element, null ).getPropertyValue("top"), 10 );
            end = start + 40;
            index = start;
            state = 'down';
            cover_element.style.display = 'inline';
            Mo.C.movePane(cover_element, pane_element, start, end, index, 'down' );
        }
        if( ( state === 'down' ) && ( index < end ) ) {
            index += 1;
            pane_element.style.top = ( index ) + 'px';
            setTimeout( function( ){ Mo.C.movePane(cover_element, pane_element, start, end, index, state ); }, 1 );
        }
        else if( ( state === 'down' ) && index === end ) { 
            state = 'up';
            setTimeout( function( ){ Mo.C.movePane(cover_element, pane_element, start, end, index, state ); }, 2000 );
        }
        else if( ( state === 'up' ) && ( index > start ) ) {
            index -= 1;
            pane_element.style.top = ( index ) + 'px';
            setTimeout( function( ){ Mo.C.movePane(cover_element, pane_element, start, end, index, state ); }, 1 );
        }
        else if( ( state === 'up' ) && ( index === start ) ) {
            cover_element.style.display = 'none';
            // signup_pass_input.addEventListener( "keypress", Mo.UserNew.enter, false );
        }
    }
};
```

**Possible Solutions**

- Wrap all in a single object called `object_all = {}`, and pass just this one variable.
- Break up the functionality in some way - likely pull out the start and end conditions to separate functions
- Move from function parameters to object properties ( statics ) to keep needed variables persistent
- ?

Comment: It's very common to pass an options object as a single parameter with multiple properties.  You can then also add new properties at any time without altering your function definition or existing code.

Comment: since it is local I will just call it var o = {};

Comment: You can use a mix of both. Like this: `Mo.C.movePane( cover_element, pane_element, options);` Where in options you define optional parameters or thos that have a default value (like zero).

Comment: Mo.C.movePane( o ); // because it looks cool :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript parameters: Having many parameters with many defaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982223/javascript-parameters-having-many-parameters-with-many-defaults)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal to use an object when there are multiple parameters.
Below you find an example of what the refactored code could look like:

```
function( cover_element, pane_element, opt ) {
  var delay=1;
  if (!opt) {
    opt = {};
    opt.start =
      parseInt(
        window.getComputedStyle( pane_element, null ).
          getPropertyValue("top"),
        10
      );
    opt.end = opt.start + 40;
    opt.index = opt.start;
    opt.state = 'down';
    cover_element.style.display = 'inline';
  }

  switch(opt.state) {
    case 'down':
      opt.index += 1;
      if (opt.index >= opt.end) {
        opt.index = opt.end;
        opt.state = 'up';
        delay=2000;
      }
      break;
    case 'up':
      opt.index -= 1;
      if (opt.index <= opt.start) {
        cover_element.style.display = 'none';
        opt = null;
      }
  }

  if (opt) {
    pane_element.style.top = ( opt.index ) + 'px';
    setTimeout(
      function( ){
        Mo.C.movePane(cover_element, pane_element, opt);
      },
      delay
    );
  }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Mo.C.movePane(elem1, elem2);
```

The delay when it switching directions is now 2000 instead of 2001.

Answer (score 1):

@mVChr has the right answer: pass a single object with properties for various parameters.  This is a standard paradigm that makes many interfaces very clean.  See jQuery's `$.ajax()` method as a great example.

Answer (score 1):

Using object is recommended. You can also do as given below

```
function movePane() {
    var a = arguments; // to make it easy
    var name = a[0];
    var age = a[1];
    var place = a[2];
    console.log(name, age, place)
}

movePane("abc", 28, "def");
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment answer:

Using the object o.  Note you do not have to initialize object properties to use them.  Very Concise.

```
        var o = {};
            o.cover_element = cover_element;
            o.pane_element = pane_element
            o.state = 'begin';
        Mo.C.movePane( o );
        return o_p;
    },
    movePane: function( o ) {
        if( ( o.state === 'begin' ) ) { 

            // start

            o.start = parseInt( window.getComputedStyle( o.pane_element, null ).getPropertyValue("top"), 10 );
            o.end = o.start + 40;
            o.index = o.start;
            o.state = 'down';
            o.cover_element.style.display = 'inline';
            Mo.C.movePane( o );
        }
        else if( ( o.state === 'down' ) && ( o.index < o.end ) ) { 

            // move down

            o.index += 1;
            o.pane_element.style.top = ( o.index ) + 'px';
            setTimeout( function( ){ Mo.C.movePane( o ); }, 1 );
        }
        else if( ( o.state === 'down' ) && ( o.index === o.end ) ) { 

            // pause

            o.state = 'up';
            setTimeout( function( ){ Mo.C.movePane( o ); }, 2000 );
        }
        else if( ( o.state === 'up' ) && ( o.index > o.start ) ) { 

            // move up

            o.index -= 1;
            o.pane_element.style.top = ( o.index ) + 'px';
            setTimeout( function( ){ Mo.C.movePane( o ); }, 1 );
        }
        else if( ( o.state === 'up' ) && ( o.index === o.start ) ) { 

            // complete

            o.cover_element.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: IMHO there are a couple of problems with your code (that I corrected in my example above). The first one is that you test for the same state in several places. It's slower and error prone. Your code will not work if index for some reason gets larger than `end` or lower than 'start'. Your delay when switching direction is 2001ms, but one gets the impression from your code that is was supposed to be 2000ms. It works for your code like it looks now, but how knows what it will look like when you och someone else change your code in the future. And there are a loots of repeat int the code.